# Why does my puppy have multiple hiccups when my other dogs don't?

Tags: health, dogs

When my 6-month-old male puppy gets hiccups, he has 2-to-3 hiccups in sequence.  My other two dogs have normal hiccups, the same sort I've come to expect from humans.  He has done this since he was a few weeks old till his current 6-month-old state.

Is something I should be worried about?

Comment: It depends on eating habits, does your puppy eats faster then your other dogs?

Comment: Yes, he eats faster than my other dogs (not unusual for puppies) and I only found it very weird that his hiccups are different than regular hiccups on another dog (even when puppies).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dogs get hiccups for a variety of reasons including eating too fast (common with dogs, especially puppies), stress, excitement, or even hypothermia. If the hiccups are not lasting for very long (you don't really indicate how long, so I'm assuming they're short-lived) then I wouldn't be concerned even if they're a little funny, humans can have funny hiccups too. At any rate, puppies are more prone to hiccups than full-grown dogs, so you should see a reduction as he gets older and maybe even a smoothing out.

If you are a little concerned still and want to help, you can always give him some water or massage his chest to help loosen and relax his diaphragm muscles. If the hiccups do go on for an extended period of time, then taking him in to see a vet is a good idea.

Some good detail on doggy hiccups can be found on [Vetinfo](http://www.vetinfo.com/do-dog-hiccups-require-treatment.html).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, the hiccups are rare, he does eat pretty fast; but it hasn't happened in a while and the the hiccups don't last very long. I was just wondering if it was weird or not, I've never seen this tempo of hiccups on a human and I didn't find much information about it online for humans or dogs.

Answer (score 1):

Its entirely normal for dogs to get the hiccups at a young age.  But there are many reasons which could be a bit more serious.  I would suggest that your dog is still at an age where it is common but if you had an older dogs that gets the hiccups commonly then you would want to see a vet.

There are many natural solutions and natural remedies which may help (see http://topdogtips.blogspot.com/2016/10/natural-remedies-to-cure-dog-hiccups.html).  Sometimes it is just the food and moving to a low grain diet will help a lot.